# Promise, await/async and Promise.all: When all this is resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, axios

I'm writing a node code that connect to an API in order to get some data. I use JS Promise to call the API and get the data on the resolve part. Now I need to call different endpoints to get  a complete data. So I ended up with Promise.all. But I can't make it work. I read that the async function return a Promise as well. So maybe my code is not handling properly the async/Promise methods.

I did a codepen with a similar code I have. I cannot get the last log to be written. This log is written when the Promise.all is resolved...

```js
const getEntitiesData = async function () {
  await getEntities().then(function (response) {
    console.log("All entities: " + response.join(", "));
    const entitiesData = response.map(function (entity) {
      getEntityData(entity).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      });
    });
    return entitiesData;
  });
};

const getEntities = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
};
const getEntityData = function (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id*1000, { id: id, ref: "!"+id });
  });
};

const data = getEntitiesData();
Promise.all(data).then(function (response) {
  console.log("All Data get: " + response);
});
```

Thanks for any help. What am I missing?

Comment: is there you're trying to use Promise.all on a single Promise?  getEntitiesData() isn't returning anything, you need a return on the await

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: Please put the code relevant to your question IN YOUR QUESTION, pasted as text and formatted appropriately.  This makes your question searchable, it works better for mobile users, it won't change in the future as external links have a habit of disappearing or changing and it's the rules here.

Comment: Lots of problems here.  First problem is that the `response.map()` callback needs to return it's promise and the `.then()` handler inside that callback needs to return it's value.

Comment: Ah OK Sorry for the code. Thanks @user120242 for the edit.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought that the map was "replacing" the array value by the function.
So OK, you say that I need to return `getEntityData(entity).the...`?

```js
const entitiesData = response.map(function (entity) {
      return getEntityData(entity).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        return response;
      });
    });
```

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array based on what you return from the `.map()` callback.  It's a bit hard to read multi-line code in comments, but I think you've made the two changes I suggested there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just aren't returning values in all of your then callbacks.  I've just added returns in every then callback function.

Using async/await:

```js
const getEntitiesData = async function() {
  const responses = await getEntities();
  console.log("All entities: " + responses.join(", "));

  const entitiesData = responses.map(async function(entity) {
    const response = await getEntityData(entity);
    console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));

    return response;
  });

  return Promise.all(entitiesData);
};

const getEntities = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
};
const getEntityData = function(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id * 1000, {
      id: id,
      ref: "!" + id
    });
  });
};

const data = getEntitiesData();
data.then(function(response) {
  console.log("All Data get: " + JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

```js
const getEntitiesData = function () {
  return getEntities().then(function (response) {
    console.log("All entities: " + response.join(", "));
    const entitiesData = response.map(function (entity) {
      return getEntityData(entity).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        return response;
      });
    });
    return entitiesData;
  }).then(p=>Promise.all(p));
};

const getEntities = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
};
const getEntityData = function (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id*1000, { id: id, ref: "!"+id });
  });
};

const data = getEntitiesData();
data.then(function (response) {
  console.log("All Data get: " + JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Comment: Hi @user120242 ! Thanks for your answer. I am wondering how the `.then(p=>Promise.all(p))` is working... Is the then that is always fired for a promise? I don't understand how this can return an array of Promise. It's working so OK but I can see how it's working. I am seeing that it will return a Promise.all with only the first Promise (p)...

Comment: entitiesData is an array of promises, so it ends up being a Promise that emits an array of Promises.  I catch the array of promises in p and then return Promise.all, so I get the final Promise that resolves to an array of values at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing returns in your async functions.
Also, when you call `getEntitiesData`, you are not awaiting it. So, it gives you a promise of list of promises. When you await, you get the inner list of promises, to which you can do `Promise.all()`.

Below code works in this light.

Do you want to get better at this? See if you can avoid `.then()` altogether. When you mix await and then, it becomes really confusing.

```js
const getEntitiesData = async function () {
  return await getEntities().then(function (response) {
    console.log("All entities: " + response.join(", "));
    const entitiesData = response.map(function (entity) {
      return getEntityData(entity).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        return JSON.stringify(response);
      });
    });
    return entitiesData;
  });
};

const getEntities = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
};
const getEntityData = function (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id*1000, { id: id, ref: "!"+id });
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  const data = await getEntitiesData();
  Promise.all(data).then(function (response) {
    console.log("All Data get: " + response);
  });
}

main();
```

So, here's the no-then() version:

```js
const getEntitiesData = async function () {
  let response = await getEntities();
  const entitiesData = response.map(async function (entity) {
    let response = await getEntityData(entity);
    console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    return JSON.stringify(response);
  });
  
  return entitiesData;
};

const getEntities = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
};
const getEntityData = function (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id*1000, { id: id, ref: "!"+id });
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  const data = await getEntitiesData();
  const response = await Promise.all(data);
  console.log("All Data get: " + response);
}

main();
```

but it does not make a lot of sense to return a promise of list of promises. I like this better:

So, here's the no-then() version with a better structure:

```js
const getEntitiesData = async function () {
  let response = await getEntities();
  const entitiesData = response.map(async function (entity) {
    let response = await getEntityData(entity);
    console.log("Entity data: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    return JSON.stringify(response);
  });
  
  return Promise.all(entitiesData);
};

const getEntities = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
};
const getEntityData = function (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id*1000, { id: id, ref: "!"+id });
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  const response = await getEntitiesData();
  console.log("All Data get: " + response);
}

main();
```

Comment: I like your examples. You just forget, like me, to return the response in the resolve of getEntityData(entity)

Comment: Thanks and you are right. I also overlooked one then in the first function. I just edited it, now the last line should be printed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getEntities() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Getting all entities");
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
}

function getEntityData(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Getting entity ${id} data`);
    setTimeout(resolve, id*1000, { id: id, ref: "!"+id });
  });
};

async function getEntitiesData() {
   const entities = await getEntities();
   const entitiesData = entities && entities.map(entity => await getEntityData())
}

const data = await getEntitiesData.map(response => console.log("All Data get: " + response);
```

Hello MuyBien, I tried to clean the code a bit. And the part you're missing in the above code is `await` in `getEntityData(entity).then(function (response) {` and `return` too.